# How to change shipping cost depends on change subtotal in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, fee

$30.00 (delivery charges are waived if orders are ≥$150.00 excluding delivery arrangement additional charge),
$50.00 (delivery charges are waived if orders are ≥$500.00 excluding delivery arrangement additional charge),

For this reason, I wrote this script. this script is not working. Can anyone help me?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 );
function discount_based_on_cart_total( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_subtotal(); // Cart total  

    if($cart_total >= 400){

      $shipping = 30;  

    }elsef($cart_total  >= 1000){

      $shipping = 50;  
    }    
   
   $cart_object->add_fee( "shiping", +$shipping, true );
    
}
```

Comment: Your code adds a fee based on certain conditions but has nothing to do with changing shipping costs, can you clarify this?

Comment: while subtotal cost is ≥$150.00 shipping cost would be $30. total cost $180. same way subtotal cost is ≥$500.00 shipping cost would be $50. total cost $550. I want this result. I think this fee based conditions can be full-fill my requirement.  @7uc1f3r Can you re-write this script.